# How is the for loop functioning in the following code for counting number of occurrences of each letter in a string?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

In this example, `setdefault()` has been used in some manner which I am not able to understand. How does it exactly help in order to count the characters?

```
print("Please enter the text : ")  
message = input()
count = {}
for i in message:
    count.setdefault(i,0)
    count[i] = count[i] + 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Also, you're wasting the return value of `setdefault` in your code. You could do this instead: `for i in message: count[i] = count.setdefault(i, 0) + 1`.

Comment: Yes I get that setdefault() will check for key in the dictionary and return the value, and if that is not available it will return the default value. What I do not understand is how by putting it inside the for loop is helping to count the characters.@ForceBru